# FTP login without username and password using ruby

Tags: ruby, ftp

I need to transfer files using  ftp server has without credentials using ruby:
my code  is here:

```
require 'net/ftp'
```

## Login to the FTP server

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new("my ipaddress")
```

It shows 530:login incorrect access error how to recover thiS

Thanks,
indra

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example with a real IP?

For instance, this here works fine:

**ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.ruby-lang.org')**

It's hard to reproduce a 530 error that you show for FTP sites that do not require user login credentials.

Comment: ftp = Net::FTP.new("172.12.2.3") like this

Comment: You are right - this one just errors out. And there does not seem to be any way to not want to connect ... it however also does not work via browser, whereas the example of ftp.ruby-lang.org will work in the browser, even without login information.